# Are there any new hidden features in the latest iOS update 9.3?

Tags: iphone, ios

I just updated my iPhone 5S to the latest version of iOS (9.3). On the official Apple website, they list [some of the most important new features](http://www.apple.com/ios/updates/) of this release.
My question is: are there any other hidden features (even minor changes) that may haven't be listed there? Thanks in advance.